# Detect tap on child bones

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, scenekit

I have a dae object with some bones. I want to detect a tap on a specific bone with the method :

```
- (NSArray *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint options:(NSDictionary *)options;
```

This method only returns the parent node, wherever i tap on the object.
How can i handle it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about a node in the context of a `SCNSkinner` ? If so bones will never be returned in a hit test result as they don't have any geometry. Bones don't have any thickness so they can't be hit, only geometry (actual triangles) can.

Comment: Ok that's why. Can i guess the the hit with position comparison ? Is it possible to trick it ?

Comment: or is it possible to convert the nodes position to 2d and check the rect for the click event ?

Comment: bones are used as sort of a skinner that is used to deform a geometry. The geometry can be hit-tested from the `geometryIndex` (index of the geometry *element*), the `faceIndex` and the skinner information you should be able to retrieve the bone. **But** what are you trying to do? Why do you need the bone?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Bones do not have geometry to be hit.

One trick you can use is creating a simple invisible box on every bone. Combine those boxes and apply the skelleton to it. Then, check the  hit test's `geometryIndex`.

Another way would be to create a very simple mesh in your 3D software, that follows the bones with no details make it invisible and bind it to the skeleton as well. Make note of the position of each  polygon and check against the `faceIndex` of te hit test.